# How to implement the visual web part into the MOSS 2007 site?

Tags: 2007, web-part

i have created the Visual web part for SP2010 site, What i need is i have implement it into this into MOSS 2007 site.

Is MOSS2007 support visual web part,and how to do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a web user control and do the necessary code behind.
2. Specify the fully qualified name of the assembly in the ascx file **Inherits** attribute, so that code can be deployed to GAC and the ascx file can read it from there.
3. Set the deployment location for the ascx file to the /_controltemplates/ folder (in 12 hive) in feature you will use to deply the soutions.
4. Add a web part in the same solution and load the ascx file using this.Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
5. Deploy the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jan Tielen's 'Smart Part'](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2006/12/02/announcing-the-return-of-the-smartpart.aspx) that allows any ascx file to be hosted in SharePoint 2007.